# passing multi-dimensional arrays as function arguments

Tags: c, arrays

As we know, when passing arrays as function arguments, only the first dimension's size can be empty, the others must be specified.

```
void my_function(int arr[5][10][15]); // OKAY!
void my_function(int arr[][10][15]); // OKAY!
void my_function(int arr[][][15]); // WRONG!!!
void my_function(int arr[][][]); // WRONG!!!
```

What is logic behind this? Could someone explain the main reason?

Comment: I expect there are duplicates for this.

Comment: Array type arguments are actually just passing pointers to the first element. The size of the array pointed to is never actually checked and the first dimension doesn't matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passing arrays to a function is an illusion: arrays instantly *decay* to a pointer when you use them. That is, with this example:

```
int foo[10];
foo[1];
```

the way this is interpreted by the compiler, in `foo[1]`, `foo` is first transformed to a pointer to element 0 of `foo`, and then subscripting is the same as `*(pointer_to_foo + 1)`.

However, this is only possible with the first dimension of an array. Suppose this:

```
int foo[5][5];
```

This puts 25 integer elements contiguously in memory. It is not the same as `int** foo`, and not convertible to `int** foo`, because `int** foo` represents some number of pointers to some number of pointers, and they don't have to be contiguous in memory.

While it's legal to use an array type as a function parameter, the compiler builds it identically to if you had specified a pointer to the array's element type:

```
int foo(int bar[10]); // identical to `int foo(int* bar)`
```

But what happens if you pass a multi-dimensional array?

```
int foo(int bar[5][5]); // identical to what?
```

Only the first dimension of the array can undergo decay. The equivalent signature for `int foo` here would be:

```
int foo(int (*bar)[5]); // identical to `int foo(int bar[5][5])`
```

where `int (*bar)[5]` is a pointer to an array of 5 integers. Stacking up more dimensions doesn't change the idea, only the first dimension will decay, and the other dimensions need to have a known size.

In other words, you can skip the first dimension because the compiler doesn't care about its size, as it instantly decays. However, subsequent dimensions do not decay at the call site, so you need to know their size.

Comment: @aj.toulan, yes, but keep in mind that C is not fundamentally a structurally-typed language. Even if two types are laid out the same in memory, it doesn't mean that C considers them to be the same for any other purposes.

Comment: @aj.toulan Yes it is. But when you access an array 2-dimensionally, `b[i][j]` it needs to know the width of each row.

Comment: It might be best if you said it clearly, rather than alluding.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays in C and C++ are stored contiguously in memory.  In the case of a multidimensional array, this means you have an array of arrays.

When you traverse an array, you don't necessarily need to know how many elements are in the array.  You do however need to know the size of each element of the array so you can jump to the correct element.

That's why `int arr[][][15]` is incorrect.  It says that `arr` is an array of unknown size elements are of type `int [][15]`.  But this means you don't know how big each array element is, so you don't know where each array element it in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with two bits of standardese:

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
> unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
> type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points
> to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
> register storage class, the behavior is undefined.
> ...
> **6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
> ...
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
> *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the
> array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding
> actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many
> elements as specified by the size expression.

<sup>*[C 2011 online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Lovely.  What does all that mean?

Let's start with the declaration of an array of some arbitrary type `T`:

```
T arr[N];
```

The type of the *expression* `arr` is "N-element array of `T`" (`T [N]`).  Unless that expression is the operand of the unary `&`, `sizeof`, or `_Alignof` operators as specified in 6.3.2.1/3 above, then the type of the expression is converted ("decays") to "pointer to `T`" (`T *`) and the value of the expression is the address of the first element - i.e., `&arr[0]`.

When we pass `arr` as a parameter to a function, as in

```
foo( arr );
```

what `foo` actually receives is a pointer, not an array, and you would write the function prototype as

```
void foo( T *arr )
```

*Or...*

As a notational convenience, C allows you to declare the formal parameter using array notation:

```
void foo( T arr[N] )
```

or

```
void foo( T arr[] )
```

In this case, both `T arr[N]` and `T arr[]` are "adjusted" to `T *arr` as per 6.7.6.3/7 above, and all three forms declare `arr` as a pointer (this is *only* true for function parameter declarations).

That's easy enough to see for 1D arrays.  But what about multidimensional arrays?

Let's replace `T` with an array type `A [M]`.  Our declaration now becomes

```
A arr[N][M]; // we're creating N M-element arrays.
```

The type of the expression `arr` is "N-element array of M-element arrays of `A`" (`A [M][N]`).  By the rule above, this "decays" to type `pointer to *M-element array* of`A`" (`A (*)[M]`).  So when we call

```
foo( arr );
```

the corresponding prototype is

```
void foo( A (*arr)[M] )1
```

which can also be written as

```
void foo( A arr[N][M] )
```

or

```
void foo( A arr[][M] );
```

Since `T arr[N]` and `T arr[]` are adjusted to `T *arr`, then `A arr[N][M]` and `A arr[][M]` are adjusted to `A (*arr)[M]`.

Let's replace `A` with another array type, `R [O]`:

```
R arr[N][M][O];
```

The type of the expression `arr` decays to `R (*)[M][O]`, so the prototype of `foo` can be written as

```
void foo( R (*arr)[M][O] )
```

or

```
void foo( R arr[N][M][O] )
```

or

```
void foo( R arr[][M][O] )
```

Are you starting to see the pattern yet?

When a multi-dimensional array expression "decays" to a pointer expression, only the first (leftmost) dimension is "lost", so in a function prototype declaration, only the leftmost dimension my be left blank.

---

1. Since the subscript `[]` operator has a higher precedence than the unary `*` operator, `A *arr[M]` would be interpreted as "M-element array of pointers to `A`", which is not what we want.  We have to explicitly group the `*` operator with the identifier to properly declare it as a pointer to an array.